# WPF Code-behind equivalent

Tags: c#, wpf, button, code-behind

When developing, I like to try and understand more than "just do this".  Especially with WPF, I like to understand BOTH aspects of the bindings... both from the GUI (xaml) and from the code-behind.  That being said, I am wondering what the code equivalent would be for the following.

I have a ViewModel with some pre-defined "ICommand" instances, such as add, edit, save, cancel, exit, whatever -- and they work as expected.  Now, looking at the binding of the View (Window) that has a button on it, I have it's binding to the commands, something like.

```
<Button Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" Content="Exit" ... />
```

and this properly does what I expect for allowing the form to exit (and do whatever else I'm playing with).

What would the code-behind look like for this.  I know that with properties, such as IsEnabled or IsVisible are bound to dependency object / properties, but I don't understand the correlation when binding to a command's execution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create the Command Binding the same way you would any other binding in code behind.

For example,

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = myViewModel;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("ExitCommand");
MyButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, b);
```

Command bindings expect to be bound to an object of type `ICommand`. When they get executed, such as on a Button Click, they first call `ICommand.CanExecute()` and if that is true then they call `ICommand.Execute()`. If the `CommandParameter` property is set then that is used when evaluating `CanExecute` and `Execute`

With WPF Buttons that have a Command binding, the `IsEnabled` property is automatically bound to the result of `ICommand.CanExecute`. The `CanExecute` method is run once when the button is first loaded, and run again anytime the Command Binding changes.

If you want it to update more frequently, such as when the `CommandParameter` changes, you need to hook up something extra to update the binding when the `CommandParameter` changes. Most `RelayCommands` I see have this built-in, such as MVVM Light's `RelayCommand`, althought other commands such as Microsoft PRISM's `DelegateCommand` do not have this behavior by default.

Comment: Yup, got the ICommand part, but wanted to be sure because it didn't look like a "Property", but I guess anything is bindable in WPF... :)